# SSH into AWS Cloud9 Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys, aws-cloud9

I would like to SSH into my Amazon Web Services (AWS) Cloud9 Elastic Cloud Compute (EC2) environment, but there is no key pair assigned to the Cloud9 EC2 environment. How can I assign a key pair to that environment, so that I can SSH into it?

I created the AWS Cloud9 EC2 environment through the Cloud9 interface, rather than creating the EC2 environment and then accessing it through Cloud9. When I create EC2 environments normally, I am given the opportunity to assign an existing key pair, or create a new key pair. This option was not presented to me when I created the environment through Cloud9.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl this question is not off-topic. It's a common problem with AWS Cloud9.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You *can* SSH into a Cloud9 environment created through Cloud9. The steps are similar to [sharing a running app over the internet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-share) in the docs, but instead of sharing the app, you share the SSH server.

1. In AWS Console, find the corresponding EC2 instance.
2. In the bottom panel, under the **Description** tab, in **Security groups** row, click on the link to go to associated security group.
3. You should now be in **Security Groups** section. In the bottom panel, under the **Inbound** tab, click **Edit** and add:

   - Type: SSH
   - Source: Anywhere

   and click **Save**.
4. In Cloud9 terminal, add your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Don’t replace the existing keys or elsewise Cloud9 IDE wouldn’t be able to connect to the instance.
5. You can now SSH into the Cloud9-managed instance using `ssh ec2-user@<ip>`, or `ssh ubuntu@<ip>` if using Ubuntu AMI, for other AMIs see [default user name for the AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html#connection-prereqs-get-info-about-instance)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just to add up, for PuTTy on Windows, the private key needs to be assigned for authentication settings in order to correctly log in via SSH.

Comment: When you edit the inbound Security Group, do not use "Source: Anywhere", but restrict to your own IP address or a CIDR block range (or a collection of them) which limits the exposure of the EC2 host to IP addresses you manage.

Comment: Last time I used PuTTy on Windows it was an awful experience IIRC. I use GitBash now (because they won't let us use WSL) and I feel like I can forget about my originating terminal. I do all the windowing remotely in `tmux` so font size is about all I need in the terminal. Would be grateful for anyone else sharing their preferred terminal on Windows 10.

Comment: @Thai Is this configuration possible in a CloudFormation template (i.e. no manual steps)?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud9 is managing the underlying EC2 for you so you won't get any extra charges.
A [terminal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/tutorial.html#tutorial-terminal) is already provided by AWS but you could follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/create-environment.html#create-environment-ssh) procedure if you still want to get SSH access to a Cloud9 environment.

Comment: So it seems that I can't SSH into a Cloud9 environment that I've created through Cloud9. It seems instead that I have to create the EC2 environment separately, and then connect it to Cloud9 as per the link you provided. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is. The EC2 environment can be created and then linked to Cloud9

Comment: If you want to connect an external GUI for MySQL, then SSH is pretty useful.